# TypeError: metadata_1.Public is not a function (NestJS SetMetaData)

Tags: node.js, nestjs

My e2e test is returning `TypeError: metadata_1.Public is not a function` for a controller that is using the custom decorator `@Public()`

Some code is omitted for clarity

```
it(`/GET forks`, async () => {
    const fork: ForksModel = { 
      type: 'Full Copy', 
    };
  
    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/forks')
      .expect(200)
      .expect({ fork: expectedForks});
  });



@Public()
public async getAccountForks(@Req() req: Request) {
    const { account } = req;
    const fork = await this.service.getAccountForks(account);
    return { fork, account };
}
```

public.decorator.ts

```
import { SetMetadata } from "@nestjs/common";


export const Public = () => SetMetadata( "isPublic", true );
```

I don't know what is happening here, it doesn't complain this when running nest

This is imported

```
import { Public } from '@app/utils/metadata';
```

Comment: How do you import `Public`?

Comment: I import it like this `import { Public } from '@app/utils/metadata';`

Comment: I'm assuming then you have the module mapper set up properly

Comment: Yep, But i think it will give the same error if i start nest, but it doesn't. I already have bunch of files in that folder which i have no problem with. I'll still look at that possibility

Comment: OMG i just forgot to export the decorators from the root index! but i was still able to import it and start nest without problem

Answer (score 0):

So i just forgot to export my metadata files from the root utils index.ts!

But Nest didn't complain and the decorator was functional on my Guard when testing!